# How can I do a selectable option in Ionic & React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ionic-framework

I'm using Ionic with React and i want to do a searchable or filterable select-option that allow user to find his city easly, i found `Ioni-selectable` but its works just in Angular.

i dont know if there is another solution to do it, mean that the user can type a letter in keyboard and the list gets sorted.

that what i'm using now

```
<IonItem>
        <IonLabel position="floating"><FormattedMessage id={'post.city'}/></IonLabel>
        <IonSelect interface="popover"
                   value={city}
                   onIonChange={e => {
                      this.setState({city: e.detail.value}, () => {
                      this.activateSubmit();
                          });
                             }}
        >
        {cities ? cities.map((item: City, index: number) => {
        return (
        <IonSelectOption value={item.id} key={item.id}>
         {
          (lang === 'fr' ? item.nomFr : item.nomArab)
            .replace(' -', '')
             .replace(' –', '')
         }
    </IonSelectOption>
     );
      }) : null}
       </IonSelect>
      <IonText slot={'end'} color={'medium'}>
      <FormattedMessage id={'form.required'}/>
      </IonText>
      </IonItem>
```